# Missing rabbitmq.conf file in RabbitMQ installation

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, devops, sysadmin

I recently installed "RabbitMQ 3.12.10:Erlang 26.2" on a Linux VM. Upon checking the server status using the command [systemctl status rabbitmq-server], the console output logs confirmed that the server is active and running smoothly and  the config is as "Config file(s): (none)"
.

However, I'm having trouble locating the main configuration file, rabbitmq.conf, which should hold most of the settings. I've searched in the /etc/rabbitmq/ path but could only find the file "enabled_plugins" and not the rabbitmq.conf file.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU8cc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvTlU.png)

Answer (score 0):

rabbitmq.conf. Could be in `/data/configuration/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf`

Or install mlocate, do an updatedb, and type locate rabbitmq.conf

Comment: I have checked the default location : etc/rabbitmq/ and others path:  "/var/log/rabbitmq$ ","/lib/rabbitmq/bin". I did not find any where

Comment: The url of the management console also shows the location of the config: "empty", database directory: "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/", log file: "/var/log/rabbitmq$ rabbit@tl-test-01.log". The two paths for database directory and log files are also visible to the terminal console but where is the config file?